# Make dynamic button container in Godot

Tags: button, containers, multiline, godot

I am stuck when I try to construct dynamic button container in Godot like shown at attached video. Is there any possible way to make it easy in Godot?

Would be appreciate for your help!

[Here's my problem's description video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjdJG.gif)

Comment: There is a flow container in the asset library, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a mix of VBoxContainers with rows of GridContainers. I've worked with GridContainers a lot recently and see no problems getting that effect done. Just add your dynamic buttons to the grid in the appropriate row.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_gridcontainer.html

Noticed this is a few months later so hopefully you found a solution.